# "[Errno 111] Connection refused" on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, proxy, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my application on pythonanywhere but I am unable to connect to twitter.

Here is the error that I am getting :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/btpraasta/btp_raasta/runServer.py", line 178, in remainingRequests
return (str)(getTrend.get_remainingRequests())
File "/home/btpraasta/btp_raasta/python/getTrend.py", line 20, in get_remainingRequests
data = get_json(url)
File "/home/btpraasta/btp_raasta/python/getTrend.py", line 10, in get_json
connection = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies=proxies)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1178, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The code I am trying to run is this :-

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.server:3128'}
connection = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies=proxies)
data = connection.read()
```

And I am trying to access the following URL :-
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json'

I have a free account on pythonanywhere and verified that the API is whitelisted and I am using the proxy as described by them here (http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError).

Comment: If you're getting the "111 Connection refused" error then it's ignoring your proxy settings for some reason, or they're not the correct settings (though they look perfectly OK to me).  Have you considered using `requests` instead of using `urllib` directly?  Configuring proxy settings is fiddly, and `urllib` can be hard to code for.  `requests` is easier to use, and it picks up proxy configuration from the environment variables, so you don't need to set that up yourself.

Comment: Ah, one possible problem in the proxy settings -- maybe you're actually using https, or the endpoint you're hitting is redirecting you to https?  You could try adding `{"https": "http://proxy.server:3128"}` to your dictionary to handle that.

Comment: I did try using `{"https": "http://proxy.server:3128"}` but that didn't work out. Using `requests` instead of `urllib` did the thing. You can make that as an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying my comment to a proper answer: getting proxies to work with `urllib` can be tricky. `requests` is in general much easier to use, and it pulls proxy settings from environment variables. Definitely recommended!